# How to remove the Vulkan Overlay

Tags: vulkan, framerate

When I start a game from Lutris with Vulkan, I get the overlay in the top right that shows GPU, Driver Version, & FPS.

Is there a key combination that I can use to turn it off/on in the game? Or is there an option in the properties?

I can't seem to find a good solution to disabling this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally solve this.

Open Lutris

Configure your game

System Options (tab) > Environment Variables.

DXVK_HUD : 0

default setting is: "devinfo,fps,frametimes"